# Entity Framework field query slow

Tags: entity-framework

I'm having some trouble working with a particular ef query.  I've simplified everything down as much as I can.  I'm only querying for two columns.  Here is my model.

```
[Table("TAXROLL", Schema = "CLAND")]
public class TaxRoll
{
    [Key]
    [Column("TAXROLL_ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Column("APN")]
    public string APN { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute my query in my controller, if I do firstordefault, the results take as long as 15-18 seconds to return.  If I do a where query, the results are almost instantaneous (less than 1 second), (see my commented timing statements below.  When I say 15-18 seconds and almost instantaneous, that's where my numbers are coming from).

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(TaxRoll))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        //var start = DateTime.Now;
        //Debug.WriteLine("Starting Query");
        var apnRecord = await ctx.TaxRoll.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.APN == id);
        //Debug.WriteLine("Returning APN after " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds);
        return Ok(apnRecord);
    }
```

When I query for the primary key (Id), results return consistently fast every single time regardless of how I run the query.  This is only a problem when I'm querying for APN.  Yes, APN is indexed.  It's also unique.  I could use it as PK, and in fact I tried that.  No dice.  I know that executing a query that searches based on APN consistently returns fast when I do it directly against the database.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated -- I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: add this line on very first line of Get: ctx.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); Then post queries which EF generated.

Comment: what type of APN column in the database?

Comment: APN column is a varchar column, as is the Id column

Comment: that line does not cause anything else to appear in the log.

Comment: Ok, I figured out why it wasn't appending to the log.  This is the query it produced.  
SELECT 
"Extent1".TAXROLL_ID,
"Extent1".APN
FROM CLAND.TAXROLL "Extent1"
WHERE (("Extent1".APN LIKE :p__linq__0) OR (("Extent1".APN IS NULL) AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ROWNUM <= 1  

This query IS slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your APN Column is NULLABLE that makes EF add OR operator, 99% it makes SQL to "seek" the column (which does not use index). make APN column NOT NULL.

Comment: This is the correct answer; though I don't have DBA access to the table, in which case Ivan's answer below works well, also.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the user **skalinkin** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948914/entity-framework-field-query-slow/35950500#35950500), you can set [DbContextConfiguration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx) property to `true`.

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext()
    {
        Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that takes 15-18s

```
var apnRecord = await ctx.TaxRoll.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.APN == id);
```

Is same as

```
var apnRecord = await ctx.TaxRoll.Where(x => x.APN == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

If you are using just Where(), nothing will be materialized from the database.

Also consider using Stopwatch instead of calculating timestamps.

```
var sw = new Stopwatch(); 
sw.Start();
// do something
Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```